# Nginx reverse proxy proxy_pass, static assets and paths

Tags: linux, proxy, webserver, nginx

I've seen this problem quite a few times on the Internet, still I haven't found a real way to resolve it **properly**. The problem is the following:

We have one site listening on **127.0.0.1:8080** ; so I want to expose it to another network using another address, let's suppose **http://example.com/APPLICATION/** . The system works but all **hrefs** and **src** point to **http://example.com** rather than **http://example.com/APPLICATION** . That creates many 404 and a css/script/image-less page.

```
http://example.com/APPLICATION  ---> Calls http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

And that's fine. Now let's suppose I click an url pointing to `/secondpage.html`. I would expect to go to go to `http://example.com/APPLICATION/secondpage.html` and not `http://example.com/secondpage.html`.

Now that applies to scripts, css sheets and images. I am already aware of the HttpSub(s)Module that can rewrite href and src tags, but that implies creating "catch-all" rewrite rules that point to / .

Finally, here's the code block I'm using:

```
location /APPLICATION {
    proxy_set_header Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Comment: To clarify my request, I'm looking for something on the lines of **mod_proxy_html** that works without actually writing rules.